# ¿Cómo corrijo el error "Documento expirado" en PHP?

Tags: php

Buen día.

He tratado de hacerlo usando `session_cache_limiter('public');`, pero cuando realizo una consulta no me trae los resultados hasta que actualizo la página manualmente, ya que solo carga lo que tiene en el caché.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Intenta esto y dime que pasa:  `ini_set('session.cache_limiter','public');
session_cache_limiter(false);`

Comment: Einer, se conserva el caché, y quedo exactamente en las mismas :(